# In C# how can I check that XmlIgnore attribute is applied on a property or not?

Tags: c#

I want to check propertyInfo to determine whether or not `XmlIgnore` attribute is applied to a given property. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11):

```
bool b = type.GetProperty("MyProp")
             .GetCustomAttributes(false)
             .Any(a => a is XmlIgnoreAttribute);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typeof(string).GetProperty("Length").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(some attr))
```